# ufw rules don't block deluge

Tags: server, vpn, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to keep `deluged` on my headless Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 from functioning when the server isn't connected to a VPN (I know many threads exist discussing the best way to accomplish that; I'm not looking for alternate methods as much as a reason why mine failed).

I've set deluge to use incoming port 40000 and outgoing ports 40001:40101.
I also set `ufw` defaults to allow outgoing connections and deny incoming connections. Finally, I have the following rules in place:

> ```
>      To                Action      From
>      --                ------      ----
> [ 1] 22                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
> [ 2] 58846             ALLOW IN    Anywhere
> [ 3] 40000 on tun0     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
> [ 4] 40000             DENY IN     Anywhere
> [ 5] 40001:40101/tcp   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
> [ 6] 40001:40101/udp   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
> [ 7] 40001:40101/tcp   DENY OUT    Anywhere (out)
> [ 8] 40001:40101/udp   DENY OUT    Anywhere (out)
> ```

(and the same rules duplicated for (v6).)

You'll note I'm allowing `ssh`, and allowing a deluge thin client to connect the the daemon running on my server.

However, deluge still manages to function even when I'm not connected to any VPN (`ifconfig` confirms that only `eth0` and loopback are active).

I can't figure out why it works the way it does. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: It occurs to me that when dealing with outgoing connections, the ports set in deluge are on the local machine, and therefore should be specified in the 'from' field rather than 'to'. This, however, doesn't stop deluge from downloading/uploading either.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a guide I found on [Airvpn forums](https://airvpn.org/forums/).
It was very helpful in understanding the same problem I had.

In the following quick tutorial I will try to give
you some guidance to get a simple setup (hopefully) working. This is only
for general guidance. Adjust addresses, port numbers and protocols as
needed. E.g. If your router is on a different IP-address then adjust the
rule to fit to your needs. Also if you want to connect to a different
VPN-server use the IP-address of the server you wish to use. The IP numbers
used here are only as an example.

Keep in mind that rule ordering is
important and the first match wins! The rule which is entered first will end
up higher in the list. At the end I will explain more about this (see point
8).

1. Open an terminal window and enter the following commands and adjust them
   to your needs.
   Use su to log in as root if you haven't or place sudo before every command.
   the $ represents the prompt in the terminal.
2. Enable UFW.

   $ ufw enable

   This will enable the firewall and now you can add rules.
3. Set the default behavior to deny all incoming and out going traffic.

   $ ufw default deny out
   $ ufw default deny in

   Now all in- and outgoing traffic will be blocked.
4. Add a rule to allow traffic to your router (only if this is needed).

   $ ufw allow out to 192.168.178.0/24

   This will allow traffic to the router/internal network which in this
   case is located on 192.168.178.0/24. If your computer has multiple
   network interfaces you can add the interface which you want to use. E.g.

   $ ufw allow out on eth0 to 192.168.178.0/24

   This will allow only connections to the internal network/router on eth0.
   If eth0 is not connected and you use for example the wlan0 connection
   UFW will block the traffic and you will not be able to connect to the
   router/internal network, because only traffic from eth0 is allowed to
   connect to 192.168.178.0/24.
5. Add a rule to allow traffic to 46.19.137.114 on port 443 with UDP
   traffic. This is the AirVPN_CH-Virginis_UDP-443 server.

   $ ufw allow out to 46.19.137.144 port 443 proto udp

   This will allow UDP traffic on port 443 to the Virginis server
   (=46.19.137.144). This is needed to connect to the VPN-server. You can
   add more than one VPN-server by repeating the above rule and adjust the
   IP-address to the server which you want to add. It is also possible to
   specify different port numbers. Just change the port number to the port
   number which is needed to connect to the VPN server. If the proto udp
   part is omitted then tcp and udp traffic is allowed and if it's changed
   to proto tcp then only tcp traffic is allowed.
6. Add a rule to allow in- and outgoing traffic over tun0. This is the
   traffic from and to the VPN-server.

   $ ufw allow out on tun0

   Now it's possible for an application like the browser to connect to
   different sites on the web. All the traffic will go through the vpn
   server.
7. In the case that you use a bit-torrent client, you will also need to
   allow incoming traffic from the port which is specified by you in the
   bittorrent client (this is the port which is needed to allow peers/seeders
   to connect to the bit-torrent client (NAT).

   $ ufw allow in on tun0 from any to any port 54321

   This will enable incoming traffic which is coming from different
   IP-addresses (the peers/seeders which want to connect to your client) to
   connect through the VPN-server connection (which is tun0 here). In this case
   port number 54321 is used, adjust it the correct port number!
8. If you now enter.

   $ ufw status verbose

   You will get a numbered list which something like:

   ```
   Status: active
   Logging: off
   Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)
   New profiles: skip

   To                         Action      From
   --                         ------      ----
   54321 on tun0              ALLOW IN    Anywhere

   192.168.178.0/24           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
   46.19.137.114 443          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
   Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
   ```

   This shows you which rules are applied and what the status of the
   firewall is. When you enter:

   $ ufw status numbered

   You will get a numbered list. It will look something like this:

   ```
   Status: active

        To                         Action      From
        --                         ------      ----
   [ 1] 192.168.178.0/24           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (out)
   [ 2] 46.19.137.114 443          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (out)
   [ 3] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
   [ 4] 54321 on tun0              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
   ```

   This is a numbered list. It is important to know that the order of the
   rules is important. If you allow something with rule number 1 which
   allows for example all incoming and outgoing traffic, all the other
   rules which are specified after that will have no effect!

   And as a final notice I will also point to the possibility to delete and
   insert rules. If you enter:

   $ ufw delete 1 # and confirm of course

   Rule number 1 will be deleted and all the other rules which followed
   rule 1 will shift up in this example the list will look something like
   this (after $ ufw status numbered):

   ```
   Status: active

        To                         Action      From
        --                         ------      ----
   [ 1] 46.19.137.114 443          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (out)
   [ 2] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
   [ 3] 54321 on tun0              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
   ```

   And if you want to add a rule on a specific spot it is possible by using
   the insert command. E.g. we want to add a second VPN-server so we can
   choose a different one in the case one is down (could happen you know
   :-)) or if we want options. The command would look like this;

   $ ufw insert 2 allow out to 119.81.1.122 port 443 proto tcp

   ## this will add the SG-Sagittarii server

   Now on spot number 2 there is a new rule inserted. The other rules will
   shift down. We can generate a new list:

   $ ufw status numbered

   And the list will look like:
       Status: active

   ```
        To                         Action      From
        --                         ------      ----
   [ 1] 46.19.137.114 443          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (out)
   [ 2] 119.81.1.122 443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (out)
   [ 3] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
   [ 4] 54321 on tun0              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
   ```

This concludes the tutorial. Use it to you benefit and I hope some things
get a little bit clearer. Make the appropriate changes for you setup and
expand on it. And again the GUI version is nice, but the command-line
version is beter, it only takes a little bit of time to get used to it.

Comment: Thank you, the tip to deny by default and only enable desired protocols on desired ports from/to desired addresses could prove helpful. Although, without knowing how deluge managed to bypass the provided list, how can I be sure it won't manage to piggy-back on one of my open rules?